# Mongoose not returning a query resulting in documents >700 but mongo shell does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a user collection which has 1000 documents,when i call `find()` function using `mongoose` in `node.js`,it does not return any result or throw any error. But when i query through mongo shell it returns all results.
Neither the docs nor the err is getting consoled,it just hangs.The same     query is working when queried for less no. of documents.

```
var userschema = require('./models/profile.js');

userschema.find({ 'dept_id': data }, function(err, docs) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log(docs);
});
```

**profile.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   dept_id:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   email:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   loggedin_time:{
    type:Number,
    default:0
   },
   phone_number:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   password:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   gender:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   dob:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   profile_pic:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   city:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   state:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   country:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   },
   last_seen:{
    type:String,
    default:''
   }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('profiles',profileSchema);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link to include the `userschema` definition? I strongly suspect you haven't defined the `User` model from the mongoose instance with the above schema, like e.g. `var User = mongoose.model('User', userschema);` and you are querying with the `userschema` instead of the mongoose model.

Comment: hi,thanks for reply i have already defined usershema.

Comment: Where have you defined it?

Comment: var userschema = require('./models/profile.js');userschema.find({'dept_id':data.id},function(err,docs){
   if(err)console.log(err);
   console.log(docs);
});

Comment: @sky add your schema _and_ your model declaration to your question, please.

Comment: EDIT your question and post the code for **models/profile.js**

Comment: i have updated my question, neither the docs nor the err is getting consoled,it just hangs.The same query is working when queried for less no. of documents.